# PropTypes on Higher Order Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way for PropTypes from a component inside of a Higher Order Component to point back to where they were created?

[image]

This is a small sample but if there was multiple `EnhancedButtons` throughout an application in separate files this would be very hard to debug.

Since the Higher Order Component is ideally made for reusability we may never know the location of the component that is missing the handleClick method. The render method of `_EnhancedButton` is a variable for any  `Component` that we want enhanced.

Is there any way to make the PropTypes more obvious where they are being created such as `FinalButton` which is inserted and is an instance of `_EnhancedButton` and is missing the prop handleClick?

https://jsfiddle.net/kriscoulson/sh2b8vys/3/

```js
var Button = (props) => (
 <button onClick={ () => props.handleClick() }>
  Submit
 </button>
);

Button.propTypes = {
 handleClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const EnhanceButton = Component => class _EnhancedButton extends React.Component {
 render () {
   return (<Component { ...this.props }>{this.props.children}</Component>);
  }
}

const FinalButton = EnhanceButton(Button);

ReactDOM.render(
  <FinalButton />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The name `FinalButton` in your example won't be known to react since that is just your local variable name, but we change the name of the resulting component to whatever you want. Here I use "Final" in front of whatever the original name was.

Also, we can copy / merge the prop types over to the new element.

```
function EnhanceButton(Component) {
    class _EnhancedButton extends React.Component {
        static displayName = 'Final' + (Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Component');

        render() {
            return (
                <Component { ...this.props }>{this.props.children}</Component>
            );
        }
    }
    _EnhancedButton.propTypes = Component.propTypes;

    return _EnhancedButton;
}
```

This gives: Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `handleClick` was not specified in `Button`. Check the render method of `FinalButton`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/luggage66/qawhfLqb/

Answer (score 7):

While Luggage's answer works very well, another, perhaps cleaner, alternative is to declare your proptypes as static and declare them inside the body of the component.

```
const EnhanceButton = Component => class extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
  }
  static defaultProps = {
    children: false,
  }
    render () {
    return (
      <Component 
        { ...this.props }
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Component>
    );
  }
}
```