# Do PropTypes on higher order components get removed in production?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I've found this example for
[PropTypes on Higher Order Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847616/proptypes-on-higher-order-components)

Basically they add the propTypes to the component before returning it in the decorator. See below copy of the code.

I know that production builds of react strip PropTypes but would it strip it from an inner function like the below?

```
function EnhanceButton(Component) {
    class _EnhancedButton extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Component { ...this.props }>{this.props.children}</Component>
            );
        }
    }
    _EnhancedButton.propTypes = Component.propTypes;

    return _EnhancedButton;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React won't remove the `propTypes` of your code, it just skip `propTypes` validation in production.

If you want to remove `propTypes` related code in production, you can use [`babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types`](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types).

Besides, you can use [`babel-react-optimize`](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-react-optimize) to do further optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b1b4a2fb252f26fe10d29ba60d85ff89a85ff3ec/src/isomorphic/classic/types/checkPropTypes.js#L33), that prop types are only checked when `__DEV__` is true. `propTypes` are not removed from your code in production builds, the check is just skipped for better performance.
It will also be skipped in your case.