# Understanding React Higher-Order Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, higher-order-components

Can someone please explain Higher-order components in React. I have read and re-read the documentation but cannot seem to get a better understanding. According to the documentation, HOCs help remove duplication by creating a primary function that returns a react component, by passing arguments to that function.
I have a few questions on that.

- If HOCs create a new enhanced component, can it be possible not to pass in any component as argument at all?
- In an example such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847616/proptypes-on-higher-order-components), which is the higher order component, the `Button` or the `EnhancedButton`.
- I tried creating one HOC like this:

  ```
  // createSetup.js
  import React from 'react';

  export default function createSetup(options) {
      return class extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
              super(props);

              this.state = {};

              this.testFunction = this.testFunction.bind(this);
          }

          testFunction() {
              console.log("This is a test function");
          }

          render() {
              return <p>{options.name}</p>
          }
      }
  }


  // main.js
  import React from 'react';
  import {render} from 'react-dom';
  import createSetup from './createSetup';

  render((<div>{() => createSetup({name: 'name'})}</div>),
          document.getElementById('root'););
  ```

Running this does not show the HOC, only the `div`

Can anyone help out with a better example than the ones given?

Comment: Have a look  HOC IN REACTJS -->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432578/8621764

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A HOC is a **function** that takes a Component as one of its parameters and enhances that component in some way.

> If HOCs create a new enhanced component, can it be possible not to pass in any component as argument at all?

Nope, then it wouldn't be a HOC, because one of the conditions is that they take a component as one of the arguments and they return a new Component that has some added functionality.

> In an example such as this, which is the higher order component, the Button or the EnhancedButton.

`EnhanceButton` is the HOC and `FinalButton` is the enhanced component.

> I tried creating one HOC like this: ... Running this does not show the HOC, only the div

That's because your `createSetup` function is not a HOC... It's a function that returns a component, yes, but it does not take a component as an argument in order to enhance it.

Let's see an example of a basic HOC:

```
const renderWhen = (condition, Component) =>
  props => condition(props)
    ? <Component {...props} />
    : null
);
```

And you could use it like this:

```
const EnhancedLink = renderWhen(({invisible}) => !invisible, 'a');
```

Now your `EnhancedLink` will be like a `a` component but if you pass the property `invisible` set to `true` it won't render... So we have enhanced the default behaviour of the `a` component and you could do that with any other component.

In many cases HOC functions are curried and the Component arg goes last... Like this:

```
const renderWhen = condition => Component =>
  props => condition(props)
    ? <Component {...props} />
    : null
);
```

Like the `connect` function of react-redux... That makes composition easier. Have a look at [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose).

Comment: Why do components fire their `componentWillMount` methods multiple times

Comment: @cr05s19xx either because they have been unmounted and they are being mounted again... Or because you are mounting a new instance.

Comment: Have a look at [React's component lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

Comment: Have a look  HOC IN REACTJS -->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432578/8621764

Comment: HOC is by definition is a component that takes another component as an argument and returns a new component. So it doesn't necessarily matter whether or not it addes functionality in order for it to be considered an HOC.

Answer (score 4):

In short, If you assume functions are analogues to Components, Closure is analogous to HOC.

Comment: HOC IN REACTJS -->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432578/8621764

Answer (score 2):

Try your createSetup.js with:

```
const createSetup = options => <p>{options.name}</p>;
```

and your main.js

```
const comp = createSetup({ name: 'name' });
render((<div>{comp}</div>),
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**A higher-order component (HOC)** is an advanced technique in React for reusing component logic. Concretely, **a higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component.**

> A HOC is a [pure function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-functions/) with zero side-effects.

**Example: CONDITIONALLY RENDER COMPONENTS**

Suppose we have a component that needs to be rendered only when a user is authenticated — it is a protected component. We can create a HOC named **WithAuth()** to wrap that protected component, and then do a check in the HOC that will render only that particular component if the user has been authenticated.

A basic **withAuth()** HOC, according to the example above, can be written as follows:

```
// withAuth.js
import React from "react";
export function withAuth(Component) {
    return class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {
        isAuthenticated() {
            return this.props.isAuthenticated;
        }

        /**
         * Render
         */
        render() {
            const loginErrorMessage = (
                <div>
                    Please <a href="/login">login</a> in order to view this part of the application.
                </div>
            );

            return (
                <div>
                    { this.isAuthenticated === true ? <Component {...this.props} /> : loginErrorMessage }
                </div>
            );
        }
    };
}

export default withAuth;
```

The code above is a HOC named **withAuth**. It basically takes a component and returns a new component, named **AuthenticatedComponent**, that checks whether the user is authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, it returns the **loginErrorMessage** component; if the user is authenticated, it returns the wrapped component.

> Note: this.props.isAuthenticated has to be set from your application’s
> logic. (Or else use react-redux to retrieve it from the global state.)

To make use of our HOC in a protected component, we’d use it like so:

```
// MyProtectedComponent.js
import React from "react";
import {withAuth} from "./withAuth.js";

export class MyProectedComponent extends React.Component {
    /**
     * Render
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                This is only viewable  by authenticated users.
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Now wrap MyPrivateComponent with the requireAuthentication function 
export default withAuth(MyPrivateComponent);
```

Here, we create a component that is viewable only by users who are authenticated. We wrap that component in our **withAuth** HOC to protect the component from users who are not authenticated.

[Source](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/06/higher-order-components-react/)

Answer (score 0):

```
// HIGHER ORDER COMPOENTS IN REACT
// Higher order components are JavaScript functions used for adding 
// additional functionalities to the existing component.


// file 1:  hoc.js (will write our higher order component logic) -- code start -->

const messageCheckHOC = (OriginalComponent) => {
  // OriginalComponent is component passed to HOC

  const NewComponent = (props) => {

    // business logic of HOC 
    if (!props.isAllowedToView) {
      return <b> Not Allowed To View The MSG </b>;
    }

    // here we can pass the props to component
    return <OriginalComponent {...props} />;
  };

  // returning new Component with updated Props and UI
  return NewComponent;
};

export default messageCheckHOC;

// file 1:  hoc.js  -- code end -->


// file 2: message.js  -- code start -->
// this is the basic component we are wrapping with HOC 
// to check the permission isAllowedToView msg if not display fallback UI

import messageCheckHOC from "./hoc";

const MSG = ({ name, msg }) => {
  return (
    <h3>
      {name} - {msg}
    </h3>
  );
};

export default messageCheckHOC(MSG);
// file 2: message.js  -- code end -->


// file 3 : App.js -- code start --->
import MSG from "./message.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>HOC COMPONENTS </h3>
      <MSG name="Mac" msg="Heyy !!! " isAllowedToView={true} />
      <MSG name="Robin" msg="Hello ! " isAllowedToView={true} />
      <MSG name="Eyann" msg="How are you" isAllowedToView={false} />
    </div>
  );
}

// file 3 : App.js -- code end --->
```

[image: output]