# How do I set PropTypes for Higher Order Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes, higher-order-components, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm using airbnb configuration for eslint and it's giving me this warning:

`[eslint] 'isLoading' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)`

Is there a way to set PropTypes for isLoading?

```
const withLoading = Component => ({ isLoading, ...rest }) =>
  (isLoading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : <Component {...rest} />);
```

Here's an example of how I use it:

```
const Button = ({ onClick, className, children }) => (
  <button onClick={onClick} className={className} type="button">
    {children}
  </button>
);
Button.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};
Button.defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {},
  className: '',
  children: 'Click me',
};

const Loading = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
);

const withLoading = Component => ({ isLoading, ...rest }) =>
  (isLoading ? <Loading /> : <Component {...rest} />);

// How do I set propTypes for isLoading?
// I tried this but it didn't work:
// withLoading.propTypes = {
// isLoading: PropTypes.bool
// };

const ButtonWithLoading = withLoading(Button);

// The rendered component is based on this boolean.
// isLoading === false:  <Button /> is rendered
// isLoading === true:   <Loading /> is rendered
const isLoading = false;

ReactDOM.render(
  <ButtonWithLoading
      isLoading={isLoading} 
      onClick={() => alert('hi')}
  >Click Me</ButtonWithLoading>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've also posted it to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BernieLee/5kn2xa1j/36/

Comment: Yes, just set `withLoading.propTypes = { isLoading: PropTypes.bool };`.
Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847616/proptypes-on-higher-order-components I think

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Larce. I tried that, but it didn't work I think because `isLoading` is in the props for `Component`, not `withLoading`. See my reply to Chamidu below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
const withLoading = (Component) => {
  const wrapped = ({ isLoading, ...rest }) => (
    isLoading ? <div>Loading</div> : <Component {...rest} />
  );
  wrapped.propTypes = {
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  };
  return wrapped;
};
withLoading.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.element,
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, @MaelFr

Comment: If you're using `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`, and if you intend to use hooks inside your inner component, you'll need to name your inner functional react component `Wrapped` with a capital W, otherwise eslint will throw an error `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing isLoading is a boolean

```
withLoading.propTypes = {
    isLoading: React.PropTypes.bool
};
```

Comment: You're right, Chamidu, I should have said isLoading is a boolean

But isLoading is in the props of the wrapped Component, not withLoading.

I tried this:

`Component.propTypes = { isLoading: PropTypes.bool, };`

If I try that, I get this warning:

`[eslint] 'Component' is not defined. (no-undef)`

'Component' is the placeholder name for whatever component is passed in to be wrapped.

Comment: Could you please add little more code here..
How are you using "withLoading" component.

Maybe some JSX

Probably you have to add propTypes  to wrapped component.

But I can not give you more accurate answer without seeing the implementation

Comment: Remove "Component => " part and check whether it is working.