# React.js PropType validation on stateless HOC and eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Let's assume I have kinda HOC, where I want to show preloader instead of content and it should be depend on props:

```
const Preloader = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    return (
      props.loading ?
        <div className="someclass">
         ...preloader stuff
        </div> :
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    );
  };
};

export default Preloader;
```

I've tried it with:

```
Preloader.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
};
```

But, obviously it won't work.

How can I validate props of my anonimous function?
What is really correct way to achieve it, coz currently I just shut down my linter (react/prop-types) to hide error.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970806/how-do-i-set-proptypes-for-higher-order-functional-component) answers yours.