# How to write PropTypes for Higher Order Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, react-proptypes

I would like to know **how to write the PropTypes in this particular situation**.

For architectural reasons, in this project some components are injected via specific library, and long story short **I need it to be a function that returns a functional component**. Like this:

Simplified code:

```
const CardPayment = () => ({
    isCancelDisabled,
}) => {
    // code
}
```

What I have tried so far:

- Normal PropTypes <-- eslint error: says that isCancelDisabled is missing in props validation
- React.PropTypes   <-- is deprecated
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970806/how-do-i-set-proptypes-for-higher-order-functional-component) other SO answer <-- did not work
- `CardPaymentUS.propTypes = {
  _: PropTypes.func(PropTypes.any),
  };`   <-- this neither

Note: the other SO answers do not consider the case where the first function takes no param.

So I would like to know if you have any other alternative. If not, the way will be to disable eslint for these cases. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your higher order function take no paramter?
Is it like

Comment: Is it like 
Componet = CardPayment();
<Component />?

Comment: Yes. It is related with the injection library. The first function takes no param and then the HOF is consumed something like this:   `const myComp = useInjection('someTag')`  . And then, the library has some config where that tag matches with CardComponent.

Comment: When I render myComp I do this:  `{myComp({ isCancelDisabled })}`

Comment: should your myComp not be called like this <MyComp iScancelDisabled={isCancelDisabled />.
Otherwise it's just like calling a js function with arguments.

Comment: Exactly. Is a call to JS function with argument. But I get a eslint react/prop-types error: isCancelDisabled is missing in props validation